# "I'm debating" instead of "I'm in a dilemma"

Tags: meaning

I have noticed many people say "I'm debating" when they mean they are in a dilemma between two choices.  I always thought that to debate means discussing different view points between two individuals, not within the head of a single person, therefore debating here seems like an incorrect usage of the term but I am not sure.

Can somebody please clarify?

Comment: My favorite phrasing has always been ["I'm on the horns of a dilemma"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilemma), which nicely conveys the potential anguish of the situation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*[Debate](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/debate)* can be used as a verb to mean *consider a possible course of action in one’s mind before reaching a decision*. For example,

> Jason **debated** whether to take the train or the bus to Berlin for his
>   mission.

Answer (score 9):

The usage of "I'm debating" is not incorrect here, it may actually be more appropriate than "I'm in a dilemma" in some situations.

A *dilemma* is "a situation in which a difficult choice has to be made between two or more alternatives, esp. equally undesirable ones." Using the word *dilemma* when the choices are not dire is a form of hyperbole.

The way you've defined *debating* is only partially correct; *debating* is not strictly between two people.  *Debating* can also mean "to consider a possible course of action in one's mind before reaching a decision."

It's also worth noting that in "I'm debating", the subject is active, while "I'm in a dilemma", the subject is passive.

Webster definitions:

- [*dilemma*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dilemma)
- [*debate*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/debate)

Answer (score 1):

In terms of phrasing, `I'm in a dilemma between` is not something that is ever used and would sound quite awkward and broken to someone who had spoken English their whole life.

Usage of [I'm in a dilemma between](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I%27m%20in%20a%20dilemma%20between&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)

Perhaps `I'm facing a dilemma choosing between` seems more complete and natural.

As the others have mentioned, debating is not limited to multiple parties and the process it implies is just as applicable internally as well as between two or more.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please edit your answer to explain it and show the research you did that supports it.

Comment: [Being in a dilemma is much more common than facing one](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+a+dilemma%2Cin+the+dilemma%2Cfacing+a+dilemma%2Cfaces+a+dilemma%2Cface+a+dilemma&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)

Comment: @JonHanna Agreed, but the full usage cited was 'I'm in a dilemma between' which certainly isn't common and is quite nonsensical.

Comment: @JonHanna http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I%27m+in+a+dilemma+between&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=

Comment: [Hardly rare](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+a+dilemma+between%2Cfacing+a+dilemma%2Cdilemma+between&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)

Comment: @JonHanna 'I'm in a dilemma between' has 0% http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I%27m+in+a+dilemma+between%2Cfacing+a+dilemma%2Cdilemma+between&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=

Answer (score 1):

Dilemma simply means in-between decisions to make or choose one. Therefore when using the term dilemma, Don't use the word between anywhere near to dilemma because that's like repeating yourself.

Comment: Your answer would benefit from linked references and an example sentence to support your claim.

Answer (score -3):

Dilemma means a tough situation or a time where you need to choose one  out of Yes or No OR it,s a complicated time
                  Eg:I am in dilemma between two course whether to go for MBA or BBA